# np.subtract() - ValueError subtracting lists with numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy, subtraction

I gave different groups to loop over.
The `put_dict` and `incomes_dict` contain a list of Integera for each group.
Because the `incomes_dict` always contain more values, I tried to bring them to the same length.
Aim is to subtract the values.

For example:

```
put_dict[g] = [ 2,3,4]
incomes_dict[g] = [1,2,1]
desired_result[g] = [1,1,3]
```

The code:

```
import numpy as np

times = []    
for g in GROUPS:
    laenge = len(put_dict[g])
    times += np.subtract(put_dict[g], incomes_dict[g][:laenge])
```

The error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (2535,)
```

Comment: The problem is not the subtract, but it is with `+=`. Did you mean too append? use `times=[]` outside loop and  `times += put_dict[g] - incomes_dict[g][:laenge]` and you can later convert `times` to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are trying to sum a numpy array with a python list, which python doesn't understand.

I guess you want to append all the elements of `np.subtract( ... )` to the `times` array, which you can do by converting the `np.subtract( ... )` object to a python list.

```
import numpy as np

times = []    
for g in GROUPS:
    laenge = len(put_dict[g])
    times += np.subtract(put_dict[g], incomes_dict[g][:laenge]).tolist()
```